# Julia - Check if float value is an integer

Tags: julia

Is there a Julian way to check whether a float variable is numerically equal to some integer value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a simple native function in `Julia` called `isinteger()`

```
julia> isinteger(3.0)
true

julia> isinteger(3.1)
false
```